# How to turn a list with returns into one string

Tags: lua

okay so im just using an online lua compiler rn and i just want to know if i have a list that looks like this (the one ii want to use is much  longer)
`ygerne yggdrasil yhwh yi yid yiddish yids yield`

and im not sure how to input this or to convert it to a single string to hopefully make it look like
"ygerne yggdrasil yhwh yi yid yiddish yids yield"

all i need is the spaces between word and one string that will display
`local string = "ygerne yggdrasil yhwh yi yid yiddish yids yield"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
local list = { "a", "b", "c" }
print(table.concat(list, " "))
```

Please read the manual

Comment: im sorry i dont know why it never shows on here but for the input 'list' there is a new line for each word and that is my problem

Comment: so your "list" is a string, not table? provide more info about your input

Comment: okay so i have a list that is many words (not in the code yet) and the main problem is i dont know How to input it as if i did 
    `local  string = "list"`
it wouldn't work as the list spans multiple lines it takes up 1 line per word and is so long i cant manually make it one long sentence myself.

Comment: the straight forward solution would be to use a text editor to replace the linebreaks by spaces. of course you can also do this in code. if you want to use a multiline string in code you need long strings.  so your problem is that you have some multiline text that you want to use as a single line in your code?

Comment: that is correct im tryying to convert a multiline text into a single line string

Comment: if you do this once simply use a text editor... otherwise read the texts from a file line by line and concatenate the lines to your string. if you want to paste it as is to your source code use a long string, then replace line breaks with spaces.